# setOnItemSelectedListener error when using 3rd party library's spinner

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

I'm using (github.com/rey5137/material) library. Before I used it I had an activity where the user selected options from spinners. It worked fine and I wanted to use his spinner instead. I ran into one problem. When I call setOnItemSelectedListener, I get this error message in the editor

```
setOnItemSelectedListener (com.rey.material.widget.Spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener) in Spinner cannot be applied to (anonymous android.widget.AdapterView.setOnItemSelectedListener)
```

here is my java file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/68aztfjlcpwpzls/RegisterPart_2Activity.java?dl=0
(the error spot is at line 123)

here is my xml: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/28zlexz866fgn6c/activity_register_part_2.xml?dl=0
(I haven't applied it to all spinners yet only the first one)

Comment: Add this statement import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener; and replace new AdapaterView.OnItemSelectedListener with new OnItemSelectedListener and  give it a try.

Comment: I imported what you said and get the same error. here's a pic of the new code http://imgur.com/cnleP78

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot more digging around and experimenting, I found an answer to my problem.

To anyone in the future with a similar problem with setOnItemSelectedListener with 3rd party spinners, here is the solution I found to work for me.

instead of having

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
```

you need to instead put

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new Spinner.OnItemSelectedListener()
```

I get no errors and can save the item the user selected just fine

Comment: in my case it is not working. I'm using 3rd party API for searchable spinner.